# How can I call native ios api from cocos2d html5 with javascript binding project?

Tags: ios, html, cocos2d-iphone, native-methods, cocos2d-html5

Can cocos2d html5 with javacript binding project for ios call ios native api? I am looking for the way to access the ios device camera, photos, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Nope. The whole point of the JS API is to have a common subset of the API that works across all platforms (on the web you can't access the camera or a photo library), with the exception of the most commonly needed features like input.

You can write the camera etc code in Objective-C. You can then expose your methods as JS bindings as needed.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  Do you know how to expose the methods as JS binding? Or can I switch the scenes between cc.Scene and UIViewController ?

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the Cocos2d-html5 project in Cordova, then use the Cordova methods to call all the native functionality you mention